# drag and drop folders,Items in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

I need to drag and drop folders between SharePoint libraries.
Drag and drop items between list.

Those are not offered in SharePoint 2013. Do I need a jQuery script?
And if any one have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your document library and click the Library tab at the top, look for "Open with Explorer".  Click that and you will be able to drag and drop whatever files you need very easily.

Click this button on both libraries on which you are moving files.

Comment: thank you , but this solution dosent work in chrome or firefox only for IE10.

Comment: Without using IE you lose some of SharePoint's functionality.  If you are unable to use IE then you may have to find a different workaround.  This however would be a very simple and easy solution.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it? with jquery script

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way to workaround would be.  Is this a one time thing where you need to move files like this or is it something that you need your end users to be able to consistently do?  If you just need to do this yourself, I would strongly suggest using IE and just doing it the easy way.  Other than that, I don't have much extra knowledge with this scenario.

Comment: The abity to click a button in the interface and have it open in Windows File Explorer is in fact IE only.  But the ability to connect windows file explorer to a sharepoint document library is available regardless of which browser you use.  You simply Map a drive to the folder or open the network path directly.